# Very odd characters in user name and host in terminal

Tags: terminal

I am unsure of when this problem began, which has made it hard diagnose, but I have very strange and incorrect characters in my terminal prompt. I will not give the exact characters, but it involves punctuation/special characters:

```
’[e[1
```

I'm very confused at why this might be. I'm using bash in High Sierra, but I believe this problem may have persisted over an upgrade.

Output of `echo $PS1` is

```
’[e[1
```

Comment: We will need to see the prompt to help diagnose. Please [edit] your question with a screen grab and\or paste of the prompt. Also, please let us know what shell you are using as well as the version of macOS.

Comment: I'm concerned about security if I present the exact results, but I have attempted to explain in more detail.

Comment: Type he command `echo $PS1` and paste the output to the question

Comment: Thank you Allan, you suggested the solution with this.

Answer (score 5):

It was a mistake in ~/.bash_profile that I must have made when trying to configure colour differences in bash:

```
PS1=`\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\]`
```

This uses back-ticks instead of apostrophes. I commented out the lines pertaining to bash prompt and the problem is solved.

Comment: The string should be in single-quotes (`'`), not commas (`,`) or backticks. Also, it needs to be plain ASCII single-quotes, not the fancy unicode curly quotes (like `‘`, `’`, or `‛`).